# How to calculate probability of a team winning in penalty kick?

Tags: probability, self-study

I was browsing the web and I saw this chart. I understand penalty rules but I really have no idea how to calculate the numbers in the chart, right on the first line.

My idea is to consider each shot as a random variable following the Bernoulli distribution then the number of successes will be Binomial distribution. And I need to calculate the P(A - B) = 1. I find it complicated and confusing when I start to do it. I believe there's a better way.

Could you give an idea or a hint on this?

[image]

Comment: To generate this chart, I would start by calculating the probability of landing in each box.  So each row would represent a normalized set of probabilities that sum to one.  One you have those probabilities for the whole chart, you can create a second version that looks forward by summing all the possible ways for each team to win from a given state

Comment: Take the first box for instance, 58% is the probability of team A winning before the sudden death, isn't it? There are just so many possible final A-B scores (3-1, 4-1, 5-4, 4-3, etc) and combinations for each score line. I think there's a tip for that?

Comment: Can you give some context for those of us who don't understand penalty rules?

Comment: @user2974951 [Laws of the Game 10.3](https://www.thefa.com/football-rules-governance/lawsandrules/laws/football-11-11/law-10---determining-the-outcome-of-a-match) - essentially five kicks each taken alternately and the highest score wins, though if the score is then equal then one more kick each repeated until there is a winner, with the process stopping early if one team has scored more than the other team could possibly score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Laws of the Game 10.3](https://www.thefa.com/football-rules-governance/lawsandrules/laws/football-11-11/law-10---determining-the-outcome-of-a-match) - essentially five kicks each taken alternately and the highest score wins, though if the score is then equal then one more kick each repeated until there is a winner, with the process stopping early if one team has scored more than the other team could possibly score.

You are not calculating $P(A-B=1)$ but $P(A-B>0)$ i.e. $P(A>B)$.

An alternative calculation could look at the probability $A>B$ in the first 5 sets of kicks and add to this the probability of $A=B$ in the first 5 sets followed by Team A eventually winning. You can ignore the early stopping as it will not affect the probabilities Using R, this might be

```
probA <- 0.75
probB <- 0.70
n <- 5

probwininfirst <- sum(dbinom(0:n, n, probA) * pbinom((0:n)-1, n, probB))
probequal <- sum(dbinom(0:n, n, probA) * dbinom(0:n, n, probB))
probthenwin <- probA*(1 - probB) / (probA*(1 - probB) + (1 - probA)*probB)
probwininfirst + probequal * probthenwin 
# 0.584873
```

which gives the $58\%$ at the top of the chart as the probability of Team A winning overall.

---

The chart itself is calculated from the bottom-up.

The $56\%$ there (more precisely $56.25\%$ is the same as `probathenwin` above and is the conditional probability of Team A winning the "sudden death" phase. The calculation is $\frac{0.75\times 0.30}{0.75\times 0.30+0.25\times 0.70}$.

Take for example the Team A fifth kick row `A(blue)  69%(blue)  83%(red)  B(red)`.

- If after A's fifth kick, A is leading by $2$, then A has won (probability $100\%$)
- If after A's fifth kick, A is leading by $1$, then either B scores (probability $70\%$) and you get to sudden death (with A having a conditional probability of winning of $56.25\%$) or B misses (probability $30\%$) and A wins overall. So the probability of $A$ winning overall would be $0.70\times 0.5625+0.30\times 1 = 0.69375$ rounding to $69\%$
- If after A's fifth kick, scores are equal, then either B scores (probability $70\%$) and B wins overall or B misses (probability $30\%$) and you reach sudden death (with B having a conditional probability of winning of $43.75\%$).  So the probability of $B$ winning overall would be $0.70\times 1+0.30\times 0.4375 = 0.83125$ rounding to $83\%$
- If after A's fifth kick, B is leading by $1$, then B has won (probability $100\%$)

and similar calculations apply all the way up.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Henry for a great answer.  Here's the Python equivalent for his R code:

```
from scipy.stats import binom

probA = 0.75
probB = 0.70
n = 5

# Calculate the probability of winning in the first n trials
probwininfirst = sum(binom.pmf(k, n, probA) * binom.cdf(k-1, n, probB) for k in range(n+1))

# Calculate the probability of having an equal number of successes in the first n trials
probequal = sum(binom.pmf(k, n, probA) * binom.pmf(k, n, probB) for k in range(n+1))

# Calculate the probability of then winning given a tie
probthenwin = probA * (1 - probB) / (probA * (1 - probB) + (1 - probA) * probB)

# Calculate the total probability of winning
total_prob = probwininfirst + probequal * probthenwin

print(total_prob)
```